# How can I check in asp.net if checkbox was chcked?

Tags: asp.net

How can I check in asp.net if checkbox was chcked?
Here the CheckBox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="FootBallManager2013CheckBox" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your markup is not using a CheckBox server control, I'll assume you want to check the input manually.

1. You have to give the input a `name`, otherwise it can't be posted. Call it, for example, `name="FootBallManager2013CheckBox"`.
2. In the code-behind, look in `Request.Form["FootBallManager2013CheckBox"]` and see if it is non-blank. If the form element is present, it was checked; if it's not, it wasn't.

Example:

```
var footBallManager2013CheckBoxChecked = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["FootBallManager2013CheckBox"]);
```

Or, you could just use the server control, which is easier.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="FootBallManager2013CheckBox" />
```

Code-behind:

```
if (FootBallManager2013CheckBox.Checked)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change html as

```
<input type="checkbox" id="FootBallManager2013CheckBox" RunAt="Server"/>
```

then on server side in code behind

```
if(FootBallManager2013CheckBox.Checked)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can tell by the *checked* property on the checkbox:

input type="checkbox" id="FootBallManager2013CheckBox" **checked="checked"**

or code wise (vb)

```
IF FootBallManager2013CheckBox.checked = checked then
[write what you want to do]
End IF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(FootBallManager2013CheckBox.Checked)
{
}
```